# creating a webtrend function to remove duplication using js apply and call

Tags: javascript, jquery, webtrends

I have a bunch of webtrend tags to pass to the webtrend server using dcsMultitrack which is pretty simple but there is a lot of duplication of code let say :

```
1. var args = ["DCSext.name","a", "DCSext.title", "random"]; //etc ...
```

than selector

```
2. $("a", "#main").bind("click", function(){
  do some extra stuff.....
  dcsMultitrack.apply(this, args);
})

***
```

Edit:

---

```
$("a", "#main").bind("mouseover", function(){
          do some extra stuff.....
          dcsMultitrack.apply(this, args);
        })
         or maybe 
       $("#main").delegate("mouseover", function(){
          do some extra stuff.....
          dcsMultitrack.apply(this, args);
        })
    etc....
```

As of no.1 let say I have some common params `commonlogs=[];` which will be available for every selector and common ones but there will be additional params case by case than I do not want to repeat those common logs. Moreover, the arguments value I am passing is based based on some dom elements, let's say I am grabbing a value from a dom,  let's say color of the selector, name of a player etc. so basically this will have to inside the same context.

```
case:  $("#selector").bind("click", function(){
          var playername = $(this).parent().text(),
              title = $(this).closest('tr').find(".title").text(); etc etc..
         args = ["DCSext.name", palyername, "DCSext.title", title, etc ];
         dcsMultitrack.apply(this, args);
});
```

**Edit2: to clarify :**

```
 $("#selector1").bind("change", function(){
       var val1 = someval1, val2= someval2, //etc.
            args = ["DCSext.something", val1, "DCSext.title", val2]; //
       dcsMultitrack(this, args);
    });

    $("#selector2").bind("mouseover", function(){
       var val3 = someval1, val4= someval2, //etc.
            args2 = ["DCSext.something", val3, "DCSext.title", val4]; //
       dcsMultitrack(this, args2);
    });
```

> note: args there are some common params let say var `commonargs = ["DCSext.common", one, /*etc*/];`

1, 2 is repeated all across since values are different, but is there a way to remove the duplication of all this code?   I want to extract into a single function and pass only the selector and additional values.

Moreover another issue is:

```
var context = "#main,#main2";

$(context).delegate("a", "click", function(){
  something ....
 dcsMultitrack.apply(this, args);
});
```

This works perfectly but can I pass an array instead of a string as context and extract into an function ?

something like

```
var context = ["#main", "#main2"];
```

Please let me know if require more clarification .

Answer (score 1):

Your first problem (the code duplication) is easily solved by creating a function:

```
function bindClick(target, args) {
    target.bind("click", function(){
        // do some extra stuff.....
        dcsMultitrack.apply(this, args);
    });
}

var args = ["DCSext.name","a", "DCSext.title", "random"]; //etc ...
bindClick($("a", "#main"), args);

var otherArgs = ["other", "args"];
bindClick($("a.other"), otherArgs); 

// etc.
```

**Edit:** if the way you bind to events differs from one set of `args` to another, you can create a `function` that returns another `function`:

```
function createCallback(args) {
    return function() {
        // do some extra stuff...
        dcsMultitrack.apply(this, args);
    };
}
```

And use that to create the callback for `.bind()`:

```
var args = ["DCSext.name","a", "DCSext.title", "random"]; //etc ...
var callback = createCallback(args);
target.bind("click", callback);
```

This works because [a closure is created](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope#Nested_functions_and_closures) so that the anonymous function that is returned by `createCallback` will still have access to the `args` parameter, even after `createCallback` has returned and its scope has closed.

---

**Edit 2:** in response to your edited question; why don't you just do this:

```
function myCallback() {
     var playername = $(this).parent().text(),
         title = $(this).closest('tr').find(".title").text(),
         // etc, etc..
         args = ["DCSext.name", palyername, "DCSext.title", title, /* etc. */ ];

     dcsMultitrack.apply(this, args);
}
```

And use this callback when binding to events:

```
$("#selector").bind("click", myCallback);
$("#otherSelector").delegate('mouseover', myCallback);
```

This will work fine, since `this` will always point to the DOM element which triggered the event. If there's anything else you've missed in your question, but which differs from case to case, just use a function-that-returns-a-function (like I described) and pass whatever is variable as a parameter.

Hope this helps.

---

Your second problem is even simpler. Just use [`Array.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join):

```
var context = ["#main", "#main2"];
var contextString = context.join(','); // '#main,#main2'
```

Comment: thanks! very simple solution ... i totally forgot about array join...but add to first part i may have event handlers not only click..than it will not going to work ...I might need to update my question ...

Comment: @paul: I updated the answer. Please have a look. It will work as long as `// do some extra stuff...` will stay the same every time.

Comment: @paul: See my latest update ("edit 2"). Your update really changed the question, but I digress.

Comment: @PPvG..my apologies for not clearing up at first time... this approach is same since i have a callback already only difference is you have extracted it as a different function ...Moreover mycallback inside stuff varies case by case since I might have to pass different data...Moreover I end up doing same thing what I am doing now...Let me know if you need more clarification ..I will update my question

Comment: @paul: I suspect this could go on for some while. There isn't a specific question anymore, so may I suggest you clean up you code and post it on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6423/discussion-between-paul-and-ppvg)